# Unity Error "wasDirty == IsPersistentDirty()"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The Console keeps throwing the error message "wasDirty == IsPersistentDirty()". Does anyone know what this means? It dosen't show the call stack or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/animations-breaking-under-unity-5-0.311471/):

> *the applyRootMotion on the animations caused the issue*

The solution found by the OP was:

> *turn it off on offending animations and make sure the sorting layer was set correctly on the sprites*